# This branch cannot be rebased due to conflicts

Tags: git, github

I've created a PR on GitHub and it says "**This branch cannot be rebased due to conflicts**".
I already updated my master branch before creating new branch and there aren't any conflicts  with the master, please advise.

Comment: Master must have been update in the meantime?

Comment: give more informations about your status!

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to click on the `Update Branch` button and change `Rebase and Merge` to `Squash and Merge`. Github was able to execute `Squash and Merge` for me.

If you do not want to squash and truly need to rebase, then you can do it from your local CLI. Then push the changes to Github.